# An auto-start app which is developed with Qt for Android device crashes after the system start up

Tags: android, qt, crash, android-source, sim-card

To be exact, if the Android device start up **with a SIM card**，the app has a **probability** of crash, otherwise, it will not crash.

I have test the app on several devices, two devices are based on Qualcomm's android source,maybe it based on AOSP, Android versions are 5.1.1 and 6.0, the app will crash on both of them,but, **if I start the app manually,everything is ok**. the other two devices are Huawei Mate 9 and Huawei Honor 4A,it works well on Huawei devices.

I look into the Android source file:
`frameworks\base\core\java\com\android\internal\app\WindowDecorActionBar.java`
`frameworks\base\core\java\com\android\internal\widget\ActionBarOverlayLayout.java`

The `ActionBarOverlayLayout.setActionBarVisibilityCallback` method is called before the object `mContextView` is valid, so, a exception is throwed out from the function `doHide`, but, if I start the app manually, another function `WindowDecorActionBar.hide` is called, not the `doHide`, so, the app runs normally.

What really confused me is that **how the SIM card can affect the app when the android system starts up?**

Answer (score 0):

Although,I can't find out the real reason, but it does work

While the broadcast of `BOOT_COMPLETED` is received, if the SIM-card is inserted, just make sure the device have signal before call the `startActivity` method.

```
public static boolean getAirplaneMode(Context context){
    int isAirplaneMode = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) ;
    return (isAirplaneMode == 1)?true:false;
}

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){
            Intent mainActivityIntent=new Intent(context,NotificationClient.class);
            mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            if (!getAirplaneMode(context)) {
                while (tm.getSimState() != tm.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
                   if (tm.getNetworkType() != tm.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN)
                        break;
                }                
            }

            context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```